# Lenovo touchpad does not work

Tags: touchpad, hardware, lenovo

I have come to Elementary OS after a lot of tests and finally, I have it! 'cause it's Fast & Simple.

But the main problem for me is the touchpad I do not know what the problem is, just my touchpad does not work even I turn it On/Off with <kbd>F6</kbd> button that is especially for this purpose in `Lenovo b50-80`.

Consider that after suspend, **it will be active automatically** now I can turn it off with <kbd>F6</kbd> and after that, I cannot turn it on again.

So I searched for this and did something however has no effect and the touchpad still does not work, does anybody have the same situation as me? What is the key to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The ArchWiki page for Lenovo Laptops has [a section on the B50-70](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Laptop/Lenovo#Lenovo_B50-70) which mentions that the touchpad works after installing the Synaptics drivers.
This might work for your model.

1. Assuming your on elementary OS 5.1 Hera, install the Synaptics drivers with the following command.

```
sudo apt -y install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04
```

2. Create the directory `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`.

```
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

3. Then, prefer the Synaptics drivers over the default libinput drivers by copying the X configuration file to the directory `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` where it has higher precedence.
   This is mentioned in the Debian Wiki [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad#Change_to_libinput_Xorg_driver_in_Debian_9_.22Stretch.22).

```
sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

Comment: My touchpad is Elantech so it did not solve my problem but thanks for your help this might help someone else!